# Cannot setup sonata using composer

Tags: symfony, command-line, composer-php, sonata-admin

I have set up symfony using composer.

I have added some dependancies in my composer .json file like so:

```
{
"name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
},
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.3.*",
    "doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3,<2.4-dev",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",
    "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "2.0",
    "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "dev-master",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "dev-master",
    "sonata-project/intl-bundle": "dev-master",
    "sonata-project/user-bundle": "dev-master"
},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin"
},
"minimum-stability": "stable",
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "incenteev-parameters": {
        "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
    },
    "branch-alias": {
        "dev-master": "2.3-dev"
    }
}
}
```

When I run composer.phar update I get this message:

> Loading composer repositories with package information
>   Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
>   Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
>       - Installation request for sonata-project/intl-bundle dev-master -> satisfiable by sonata-project/intl-bundle[dev-master].
>       - sonata-project/intl-bundle dev-master requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
>     Problem 2
>       - sonata-project/intl-bundle dev-master requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
>       - symfony/framework-standard-edition 2.3.x-dev requires sonata-project/intl-bundle dev-master -> satisfiable by sonata-project/intl-bundle[dev-master].
>       - Installation request for symfony/framework-standard-edition 2.3.x-dev -> satisfiable by symfony/framework-standard-edition[2.3.x-dev].

So not knowing any better I figure I may need to run composr.phar install which gives me this:

> Loading composer repositories with package information
>   Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
>   Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json. You may be getting outdated dependencies. Run update to update them.
>   Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
>       - Installation request for symfony/framework-standard-edition 2.3.x-dev -> satisfiable by symfony/framework-standard-edition[2.3.x-dev].
>       - symfony/framework-standard-edition 2.3.x-dev requires sonata-project/admin-bundle dev-master -> no matching package found.
>
> Potential causes:
>    - A typo in the package name
>    - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
>      see https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion for more details.
>
> Read http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md for further common problems.

I have followed the instructions from sonata-project.org but am not making any progress.

Is there some sort of really obvious mistake I am making?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a valid composer.json for setting up sonata-admin with symfony 2.3.*

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.3.*",
    "doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3,<2.4-dev",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",
    "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "twig/twig": "1.*",
    "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle" : "1.1.*",
    "sonata-project/block-bundle" : "dev-master",
    "sonata-project/exporter" : "1.1.0",
    "sonata-project/jquery-bundle" : "1.8.*",
    "sonata-project/cache-bundle" : "dev-master",
    "sonata-project/intl-bundle" : "dev-master",
    "sonata-project/admin-bundle" : "dev-master",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle" : "dev-master",
},
```

Also you **have** to install `INTL` extension: http://php.net/manual/en/intl.setup.php

Comment: Thank you for your reply Hast. I put that in the composer.json file and got the same errors. Maybe I am doing something else wrong?

Comment: Could I safely paste the code from a zip file into the correct place and include the composer.json require section?

Comment: Nope, do not even past zipped code to vendors directory.
Your problem is also that you have to install intl extension: http://php.net/manual/en/intl.setup.php

Comment: @jaget I've added link about intl installations to the answer. Did it help you?

Comment: Just trying to set this up on mac / MAMP. I'll update you when I get it installed and tested.