# How to make composer recognize intl php extension

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, intl

I'm trying to install some symfony bundles to create an admin tool found in this tutorial: http://www.ens.ro/2012/07/13/symfony2-jobeet-day-12-the-admin-bundle/

I'm using symfony 2.3.* and am using composer for my dependencies as described here: [Cannot setup sonata using composer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17258508/cannot-setup-sonata-using-composer)

but when I try to update my symfony buid as described in the above composer file (php composer.phar update) , I get this error:

- Installation request for sonata-project/intl-bundle dev-master -> satisfiable by sonata-project/intl-bundle[dev-master].

  - sonata-project/intl-bundle dev-master requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.

now I **know** that the php intl extension is installed because it shows up in my info.php file (pictured here):
http://johnpaulwhatnow.com/intl.png

so why does composer/symfony think the intl extension isn't installed?

Specs:
Mamp|
php 5.4.10|
symfony 2.3.6

EDIT: I did find this error in my php error log:

> [24-Oct-2013 14:05:11 America/Chicago] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup:
>   Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/intl.so'
>   - dlopen(/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/intl.so,
>   9): Symbol not found: _zend_new_interned_string   Referenced from:
>   /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/intl.so
>   Expected in: flat namespace  in
>   /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/intl.so
>   in Unknown on line 0

**Solved**

I had to tell my CLI to use mamp's php, which had intl.so installed.  I did this by creating a alias: alias phpmamp='/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.19/bin/php'

then running the command I needed: phpmamp  composer.phar update  --prefer-dist

thank you for your answers!

Comment: looks to be very similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18463300/issue-with-sonataintlbundle-i-cant-install-with-composer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you probably have two php.ini... one for cli and apache.

You have to load intl extension in both.

**EDIT**

To find the php.ini that is used when php scripts run from cli use this command in the terminal:

```
php -r 'phpinfo();' | grep 'php.ini'
```

Answer (score 0):

Composer is a command line tool, it uses the PHP CLI version, and this usually has a DIFFERENT php.ini than the PHP running inside the web server.

Please run `php -i` on the command line and check if the `intl` extension is mentioned. I suppose it is not. Also it would be a good idea to fix your error with that extension. This could be related - the CLI version might have triggered the error.

Comment: oh I see - I should have guessed because i need to use "php -c /Applications/MAMP/conf/php5.4.10/" in front of any symfony commands...but where do I find the php.ini for the cli php?

Comment: also - im using a unix alias to direct php towards the php in my mamp: alias phpmamp='/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.19/bin/php'...wouldn't intl extension be installed if I specifically told the command line to use that particular php lib?